# Weird Error: The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type .... when seeding Entity Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting a weird reference error when trying to setup an initial seed to my entity database. `The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'SetupSheet.Models.SetupSheet'` I cant figure it out.  I have to have these references:

```
using SetupSheet.Models;
using SetupSheet.Models.CollectionofTool;
```

for the defining properties on the TurningTool objects.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTYll.png)

Configuration.cs

```
namespace SetupSheet.Migrations
{
    using SetupSheet.Models;
    using SetupSheet.Models.CollectionofTool;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SetupSheet.Models.DataModel>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SetupSheet.Models.DataModel context)
        {
            context.TurningTools.AddOrUpdate(
                t => t.TurningToolShape,
                new TurningTool { Id = 1, InsertRadius = .032, TurningToolShape = TurningToolShape.Diamond, CreationDate = DateTime.Now },
                new TurningTool { Id = 2, InsertRadius = .064, TurningToolShape = TurningToolShape.Triangle, CreationDate = DateTime.Now },
                new TurningTool { Id = 3, InsertRadius = .125, TurningToolShape = TurningToolShape.Diamond, CreationDate = DateTime.Now }

             );

        }
    }
}
```

TurningTool.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SetupSheet.Models.CollectionofTool
{
    public class TurningTool : Tool
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Turning Tool Shape")]
        [Index("XI_TurningToolShape_Radius_Grade", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public TurningToolShape TurningToolShape { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Insert Radius")]
        [Index("XI_TurngingToolShape_Radius_Grade", 2, IsUnique = true)]
        public double InsertRadius { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Tool.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace SetupSheet.Models
{
    public class Tool
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Type of Tool")]
        public ToolType? ToolType { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Index("XI_TurningToolShape_Radius_Grade", 3, IsUnique = true)]
        public Grade Grade { get; set; }    
    }

    public enum TurningToolShape
    {
        [Description("Diamond")]
        Diamond = 1,
        [Description("Triangle")]
        Triangle = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a type `SetupSheet`?

Comment: Does it help to move the `using`s outside of the namespace declaration in `Configuration.cs` (e.g. move them to the complete top of the file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I had a type SetupSheet.  I changed it and it is not work.  Thank Ivan Gritsenko.